# Using Java's ArrayList lastIndexOf()

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof, lastindexof

To make things simple, I have an ArrayList called "items" (which stores a string the user inputs) and this bit of code:

```
int index = items.lastIndexOf("i am");
if (index >= 0)
System.out.println("yay");
```

When I test it out, if I type in "i am" at the beginning it outputs "yay" like it should. But, if I type in something like "yes i am" it doesn't output anything. Is there a way I can have it so "yay" is displayed if I type in something like "yes i am" or am I restricted to having it just at the beginning?

Here's how I setup the ArrayList:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(user.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you perhaps do the matching on the original string (`user`)?

Comment: Actually, just to clarify that I understood the question, will you get one element List containing `"i am"`, when you enter `"i am"`? Same case with `"yes i am"`? I suppose they would be added as a single element in the list. Di I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are splitting the input string on a comma (in an awkward way too).  Since `yes I am` doesn't contain a comma, your array will only have a single element: `["yes I am"]`.  Which means that `lastIndexOf("i am")` will not match.  Hence you aren't seeing `yay` being printed out.

Now, to the matter of how to make this work.

1. Type in `yes, i am`
2. as someone suggested
   in the comment, match on the original input string with
   `user.indexof("i am")`.

Basically, it's hard to recommend a solution because I don't know what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: I went with just matching with the original string and it works so I guess I can live with that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regex doesn't split the input that you indicated. E.g., `i am` and `yes i am` will be the single element in the list. That's why in the first case you're getting `yay` and in the second -- not.

If you change user input to `yes, i am`, you'll get `yay`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)) for ArrayList says that it tests the string for equality, so "yes, i am" wouldn't work.